# which role to assign a QA engineer in JIRA?

Tags: jira

I am configuring JIRA for a small development team. The default roles in the system are 'Users', 'Developers' and 'Administrator'. I'd like to know what is the role typically given to a QA engineer in the default workflow?

If the answer is to go for a new role, I'm interested in best practices.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend only adding a new role if you have a use for it in a permission or notification scheme, or workflow. So if you're going to limit a transition to members of a QA role, that's fine. Making it a role allows project admins to manage the members, which is more scalable than using a group that has to be changed by a JIRA admin.

But if you don't have a use for the new role, don't add it